# Where is the signature of CERT.SF at CERT.RSA (Android)

Tags: android, signature, verification

I want to verify android apk's signature. (not using jarsigner lib.)
So, I have a plan like this:

1. Getting a public key from apk.
2. Getting a signature of the CERT.SF from apk
3. Verifying signature with the public key from 1.

I can get public key from CERT.RSA by using openssl command like this.
  (- openssl pkcs7 -inform DER -in CERT.RSA -noout -print_certs -text)

But, how can I get a signature of the CERT.SF in the CERT.RSA file.

If somebody knows how to get it, please let me know. 
It would be grate helpful for me.
Thank you!